# android java notification tap reset activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

i use this code for notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "notify_001");
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, 
 intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

when i tap on notification app open and restart MainActivity i dont want to restart MainActivity.

Comment: You should not use any special launch modes as they ususually cause more problems than they solve. Have a look at my answer for the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible try to add the launch modes to the main activity.

in manifest under the activity tag just use this tag. Or you can add this mode while starting the pending intent for main activity from the notification manager class.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

sample code

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="singleTask"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:taskAffinity="">
```

this should make the new launch to pass the data to existing activity if any opened and is present on back stack.

Also make sure you override the below method to receive the new data in main activity

```
protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent){
  //your update code goes here
}
```

Comment: In general this is bad advice. It may work for you this time, if you have a simple app with only 1 `Activity`, but this is a bad solution to the problem and not the way to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to just bring your app to the foreground (if it is running) or start it (if it is not running), you should use the following approach:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),
        "notify_001");
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, 
intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

This simulates clicking on the app icon on the HOME screen.